# php array_merge and array_intersect usage to merge, filter an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

i need this a lot and i was thinking there must be a way to avoid looping arrays to accomplish this task.

example arrays

```
$array1 = ['user_id'=>'1','password'=>'PASS','name'=>'joe','age'=>'12'];
$array2 = ['user_id'=>'0','password'=>'default','age'=>'21'];
$filter = ['user_id','password'];
```

Question is how can i

1. merge array1 and array2 overwriting array2 with values of array1, and adding missing keys.
2. merge `$array1` with `$array2` overwritting `$array2` with values from `$array1`, yet neglect extra data in array1 (above example should neglect name)
3. how can i unset all array_keys from `$array1` which is in `$filter`
4. how to only return part of the array from `$array1` where keys exist in `$filter`

without using loops ?

sorry if i ask for alot, but this is meant to collect most usages of array_intersect , array_merge, and array_diff and how to use them correctly.

**edit:**

Expected output

```
for 1.

    ['user_id'=>'1','password'=>'PASS','name'=>'joe','age'=>'12']; //since all array2 was overwritten and extra keys was added

2.

    ['user_id'=>'1','password'=>'PASS','age'=>'12'];

3. 

    ['age'=>'21']; //removed user_id,password from array1 since they exist in $filter

4. 

    ['user_id'=>'1','password'=>'PASS','age'=>'12'];//return only values of keys that exist in $filter
```

thanks

Comment: I'm very unclear about what some of these operations should accomplish. Please give expected results for each question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-merge array1 and array2 overwriting array2 with values of array1, and adding missing keys.

```
$a1 = $a1 + $a2;
```

2-merge $array1 with $array2 overwritting $array2 with values from $array1, yet neglect extra data in array1 (above example should neglect name)

```
$a2 = $a2 + $a1;
```

3-how can i unset all array_keys from $array1 which is in $filter

```
array_walk($array1, function($val,$key) use(&$array1, $filter) { 
    if(in_array($key, $filter)) unset($array1[$key]);
});
```

4-how to only return part of the array from $array1 where keys exist in $filter

```
array_walk($array1, function($val,$key) use(&$array1, $filter) { 
    if(!in_array($key, $filter)) unset($array1[$key]);
});
```

Comment: `$a1 = array_filter($a1, function($var) use($filter) {
            return in_array($var, $filter) ? true : false;
});` and this solve 3, and 4 if there was no keys.

Comment: not sure if my answers for 3 & 4 are the best.. There has to be a better way

Comment: @Zalaboza - did I pass your test?